# Using serif math with siunitx in a sans-serif document

Tags: fonts, siunitx

When I type using `siunitx` in math mode, it is not picking up the math font `mathptmx` but is instead using what I believe is Computer Modern Sans Serif.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
The strong nuclear force is attractive for separations between $0.5$ and $\SI{3}{\femto\metre}$.
\end{document}
```

I would like to have `$\SI{3}{\femto\metre}$` displayed in the serif `mathptmx` font.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: A general comment: Helvetica (`tgheros` is an Helvetica clone) and Times (`mathptmx` is a Times clone) don't harmonize all that well, in part because Helvetica is noticeably darker than Times.